# Injection molding - Probability of plastic pouring into connector

Tags: plastic, injection, injection-molding

I have some metal pins that I want to be molded in parts of the final assembly.

Meaning that, the mold will be made to accept those metal pins, which are positioned in the mold so that when the plastic is shot in, it will envelop the pins with plastic.

While I know that this works fine, there is a problem. I cannot find the female connectors in the exact size that I want. I can order some common ones, however, in order to accommodate the male part, they will have to be stretched out.

[image]

The initial Outside Diameter was `2.5mm`, while after stretching is about `2.8mm`.
The yellow cable is a pin header, and I left it there for reference.

My concern is that if these stretched out female connectors enter this injection molding, molded-in process, then plastic will enter through the gap and flow into the connector.

Is this a possibility, or its low gap can prevent plastic from entering? If there is a danger, is there a way to mitigate it?

EDIT: this is what i am trying to achieve, but inside there will be female cylindrical connectors:

[image]

Comment: `Is this a possibility` ... how can it not be a possibility? ... put heatshrink tubing on the contacts

Comment: One off or production? Normally would you just pot it, not *injection* mold it.

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea. Pllastic will enter through the wire crimp, the barbs and the split line. Post details of the male connector - pin dimensions, pitch, rows and columns.

Comment: if you have to ask, then assume the probability to be 100%

Comment: @Transistor I can't do that since the male connectors are inside a tubing of the original product, and it's really hard to measure them, even with a vernier caliper. However, when I stretch the female connectors to about 2.85-2.9mm, they male connectors fit fine. It is impossible (for me) to find the exact size female connectors... I have started an equivalent thread here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/686108/identifying-a-socket-contact-and-finding-a-slightly-larger-size

Comment: @jsotola I though about it, however I am not sure if there is heatshrink tubing that will withstand the temperatures of injection molded plastic. Is it possible?

Comment: @DKNguyen I am messing around right now, however if i succeed, why not small scale production?

Comment: what temperature range are you talking about?

Comment: @jsotola The temperatures used in injection molding....

Comment: So make a set of pins to make the plastic molded bit suitable for the pins you are adjusting. Those pins will go in from the back so that the ridges required will not prevent their removal.

Comment: Fill the spaces you do not want plastic to go. Rather than shrink wrap or a per-part entity, aim for tooling that goes with your mold (since you are injection molding, your quantity justifies this too right?)

Comment: @SolarMike Hm... Thank you but I have trouble visualizing this. What exactly do you mean with the pins will go in the back? Could you please describe it a bit better for me that I have no experience with this?

Comment: @Abel Thank you! I actually thought about this when I read Solar Mike's answer. However, what material you think fits best for this? Is it resin (SLA based)?

Comment: @user1584421 I was asking what is the actual temperature of the injection molding process

Comment: Material? What is your mold? Aluminum? Steel? Combinations thereof? I'd be leaning toward adding some steel pins with a flange or ridge to block the crack. Would be even better if it could be the tool that stretches your contact, allowing you to mold and stretch in one press.

Comment: @jsotola The max temperature is 300 degrees Celcius.

Comment: @Abel The molding material is resin from 3d SLA printers.

Comment: I'm asking about the material of the mold itself.  Are you injecting into SLA-produced molds? I've only seen that done with RTV.  Unfortunately dowel inserts like I envisioned would need to be a similar material to the mold, and cured SLA resin is not something I would suggest as a die/press for the contacts pictured.

Comment: @Abel Yes, I plan to inject into SLA-produced molds. I plan to buy a cheap injection molding maching that uses SLA molds. Do you have any idea on what material should I use for the insert, if the molds are SLA?

Comment: Steel and aluminum are the go-to materials.  You may have to get creative in how it inserts into your SLA molds to distribute the load or be removable (if that ends up necessary because of geometric choices).  You could always try more SLA resin, relying on the contacts themselves for the structure. Whatever the case, design assuming your injection pressure is applied against it in the direction of the material's flow.

Comment: @Abel Thanks! If you are curious, I updated the question with a picture of what I roughly want to achieve.